# How to use Gun as an express route?

Tags: node.js, express, gun

I'm trying to use gun in an express/node project, however I want to mount the endpoint as `/db`. I had hoped the following code would work but keep getting a **Route.get() requires callback functions** error:

```
var express = require('express');
var Gun = require('gun');

var app = express();
var port = 8080;

var gun = new Gun({
    file: './data.json'
});

// mount the gun db server
app.get('/db', gun.router);

// regular express route
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.send('other stuff...');
});

// start the server
app.listen(port, function () {
    console.log('Web server listening on port ' + port);
});
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Doherty!

GUN can be used with express, but it is not an express route. For example, lets first go over a simple gun server mounted with express:

```
var express = require('express');
var Gun = require('gun');

var app = express();
app.use(Gun.serve).use(express.static(__dirname));

var server = app.listen(80);
Gun({file: 'data.json', web: server});
```

( https://github.com/amark/gun/blob/master/examples/express.js )

GUN's API is now available in the browser at:

```
<script src="http://YOURSERVER.com/gun.js"></script>
<script>
  var gun = Gun('http://YOURSERVER.com/gun');
  gun.get('key').get('hello').put('world!');
  gun.get('key').get('hello').on(function(data){ console.log(data) });
</script>
```

GUN is **not** available as an express route. For example, **this does not work**:

```
http://YOURSERVER.com/data/key/hello?put=world!
```

## Why?

GUN is a **realtime database**, if you use a REST or CRUD routes with express as its API, then **you lose the realtime capabilities**. Meaning you would have to write your own custom long-polling implementation, which defeats the point of having an express route.

## I understand, but I still want a REST or CRUD API for GUN?

It should not be hard to create an HTTP route that proxies gun. Here is some **pseudocode** that should help get you started. If you build it, please make it an Open Source module on NPM so others can enjoy it!!!

```
// this is pseudocode!!!
app.get('/data', (req, res) => {
  path(req).val(data => res.send(data)) 
});

app.put('/data', (req, res) => {
  path(req).put(req.param.put, ack => {
    res.ack? 0 : res.ack = res.send(ack)
  }) 
});

var path = (req) => {
    var ref = gun;
    req.path.split('/').forEach(key => ref = ref.get(key));
    return ref;
}
```

Let us know if you build it! As always, the community [chatroom is friendly](https://gitter.im/amark/gun) and active. Ask for help there, and ask questions here. Thanks for making this a SO question!

Comment: Mark, big thanks for the in-depth answer! The reason I wanted to wrap Gun in an express route was so I could intercept initial connection requests using express middleware and reject unauthenticated users with a 401... I will of course open source whatever I cobble together :)

Comment: Ah, if you are wanting to do this for security/authorization permission reasons, then that is a very different subject. Check out SEA (Security, Encryption, Authorization) for GUN, some info is here: https://github.com/amark/gun/wiki/auth . It is in alpha though, and there are some other StackOverflow questions on it that I haven't been able to answer yet - but please add more!